# How to implement onitemclicklistener in array adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

i am confused, i want to add an onitemclicklistener in my adapter 
i have no idea how do i integrate the following code in my code.
any help would be appreciated.
here is the adapter

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (position == ITEM_POSITION_HERE)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),         ActivityName.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
});
```

and here is my java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list1;

private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",

"item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in

// list.

list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));

}

}
```

Comment: what is your confusion?

Comment: i have no idea where to insert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
         if (position ==items[ITEM_POSITION_HERE])
        {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
          startActivity(myIntent);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: AFter this line in your activity `list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));`

Comment: im getting error on "items" in the line "if (position ==items[1])"

Comment: Welcome.. and its sister. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `onclicklistener` to `listview` not `adapter`

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

  // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Comment: dude i want to open new activity on item click , not show any toast!

Comment: call Intent instead of Toast message then.  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityName.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: just put this within oncreate()

Comment: Just look. The first and last line I have in my code is where you put it in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (position == ITEM_POSITION_HERE)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityName.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
});
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to do that

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(your listener);

 onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);      

    Intent i = new Intent(this, yourClass.class);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am editing your code. Please replace your JAVA file with this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list1;

private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",

"item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in

// list.

list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
    list1 .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (position == ITEM_POSITION_HERE)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),         ActivityName.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
});
}

}
```

Do not incluse **ONITEMCLICKLISTENER** with your adapter class. Include it in you main java class

Comment: Does this helps..?? @9 6