# Bluetooth conection implements onItemClickListener and it is not working

Tags: android

I followed a tutorial to implement a bluetooth connection in an Android device but when it implements the onItemClickListener in the class it crashes.

This is my code in the class:

```
package com.technowomen.isabel.izyboard202;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.*;
import android.os.*;
import  android.widget.AdapterView.*;

/**
 * Created by Isabel on 25/07/2015.
 */
public class Conectivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  onItemClickListener {
    private static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
    private static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> listDevices;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
    Handler mHandler;
    //ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> listDevices;
    ListView listView;
    IntentFilter filter;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3 ){
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if (mArrayAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("NOMBRE_ESTEF_DEVICE")){

            BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is paired", duration ).show();
            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
            connect.start();
        }

    }

    private void turnOnBt() {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
    }

    public void init(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
        listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        /*
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ITEM CLICKED POSITION = "+String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

         */

        listDevices=new ArrayList<>();
        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    devices.add(device);
                    mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName());

                }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                    //still missing
                }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                    //still missing


                }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getState()== mBluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                        turnOnBt();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conectivity);
        init();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            // Check if Device support Bluetooth
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                turnOnBt();
            }
            getPairedDevices();
            startDiscovery();


        }else {
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected", duration ).show();
//            finish();
        }
        mHandler = new Handler(){

            public  void handleMessage(Message msg){
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                switch(msg.what){
                    case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                        ConnectedThread connected = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect", duration ).show();
                        String s = "prueba, conecta";
                        connected.write(s.getBytes());
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_READ:
                        byte [] readBuff= (byte[])msg.obj;
                        String string = new String(readBuff);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, duration ).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void startDiscovery() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private void getPairedDevices() {
        pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                listDevices.add(device.getName() + " : " + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enable", duration ).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            System.out.println("two");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            //manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

//    private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {
//
//    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

}
```

and the xml file is the following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ListView">

        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FYI I already try to use the solutions gave in [how-to-implement-onitemclicklistener-in-this-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410732/how-to-implement-onitemclicklistener-in-this-code) [how-to-implement-onitemclicklistener-in-array-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346507/how-to-implement-onitemclicklistener-in-array-adapter)

Please help me to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: It should be `onItemClick` method implemented. I see you have this `onItemClickListener` instead.

Comment: I tried the onItemClick instead of onItemClickListener and it didnt work, the implements onItemClickListener is still in red...

Comment: Its simple. Replace this `onItemClickListener` with `OnItemClickListener`. Read the docs rather than just copy paste.

Comment: Yes, you're so right, the thing is I'm a complete beginner in Android so I'm just getting familiar with it. But I already try changing both to onItemClick and didnt work either...

Comment: You are not getting my point. `OnItemClickListener` is a interface. Your activity implements the same. You need to provide a implementation for your abstract method `onItemClick` in your activity. Its java stuff more than android. The commented listview part does the same but that is annonymous inner class implementating the interface

Comment: Posted an answer with explanation check it if you have further crashes a stacktrace is required to figure out the problem

Comment: You're right, I get it know, thanks alot for the explanation!

Comment: Is your problem solved??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnItemClickListener` is the interface:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

The class that implements the interface must give a implementation for

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

The commented part

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ITEM CLICKED POSITION = "+String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

does the same but with a anonymous inner class

In your case you commented the above and you have

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

`this` refers to your Activity class. Hence you have

implements  OnItemClickListener

To get rid of errors replace this

```
 public class Conectivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  onItemClickListener {
```

with

```
public class Conectivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  OnItemClickListener {
```

And replace this

```
  public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3 ){
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    if (mArrayAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("NOMBRE_ESTEF_DEVICE")){

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is paired", duration ).show();
        ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
        connect.start();
    }

}
```

with

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

  if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    if (mArrayAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("NOMBRE_ESTEF_DEVICE")){

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is paired", duration ).show();
        ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
        connect.start();
    }

}
```